# Spark SQL Table not found after registerTempTable

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run sql query after adding my dataframe to a temporary table but everytime it displays table not found.

`emp` is the name of the dataframe.

**COMMANDS**:

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@6cb7a4c1

scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> emp.registerTempTable("people")

scala> val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE id >= 100 AND id <= 105")

java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: people
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog$$anonfun$1.apply(Catalog.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog$$anonfun$1.apply(Catalog.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:111)
```

Comment: How you are creating a dataframe--> emp.

Comment: and you are running this where scala repl or spark-shell ? what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: Share where you are creating the data frame "emp". Is the data frame "emp" is created using the same "sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@6cb7a4c1". If not it will not be visible to this context. Create the data frame,register the temp table and query from the table using same context.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved guys. Apparently I was directly using a DF created from RDD. If I create a duplicate of the DF(derived from RDD), registerTempTable will work. THanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the code changes you did to fix this? I am facing the same problem, can't seem to figure this out.